# Calculating the number of days between two dates in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I compare two dates, return a number of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548008/how-can-i-compare-two-dates-return-a-number-of-days)

I have two dates (as NSString in the form "yyyy-mm-dd"), for example:

```
NSString *start = "2010-11-01";
NSString *end = "2010-12-01";
```

I'd like to implement:

```
- (int)numberOfDaysBetween:(NSString *)startDate and:(NSString *)endDate {

}
```

Comment: Duplication? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548008/how-can-i-compare-two-dates-return-a-number-of-days

Comment: That question doesn't answer what I need. I simply want to see how to implement that method.

Comment: Duplication of [the question Meke mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548008/how-can-i-compare-two-dates-return-a-number-of-days), you can use almost the exact same code from that answer, just omit the month-flag.

Comment: Hey, I guess you got the SO idea a bit wrong. Most people aren't here to implement your methods, but to help you implement them. What have you tried, read and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of days between two NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of days between two NSDate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236719/number-of-days-between-two-nsdate-objects)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

```
NSString *start = @"2010-09-01";
NSString *end = @"2010-12-01";

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                    fromDate:startDate
                                                      toDate:endDate
                                                     options:0];
```

`components` now holds the difference.

```
NSLog(@"%ld", [components day]);
```

Comment: How exactly do we access it from components?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, why would you even need `f` to be static?

Comment: @SpacePyro: forget it, it was an pun in response I had said somewhere else.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Haha gotcha. I was worried there for a sec. ;)

Comment: I actually don't think this works correctly. Try using real `NSDate` components, and see that the result is off by 1 day, due to some not having a > 24 hour difference

Comment: @royherma: let me guess: you are not in GMT (greenwich) Timezone, but printed the NSDate object without using a NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @vikingosegundo i was more looking at just the end result - `[components day]`, and received wrong results when comparing two dates from the same time zone. Will look more into it, but pretty sure i was doing it right

Comment: I am pretty sure this code works correctly. Post your code in a new question.

Comment: @Rodrigo Do you know what `NSCalendarWrapComponents` does? I've read the documentation but I don't understand it... And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524895/cocoa-calculate-working-days-between-two-dates#comment39891487_25526960) they say that you should use options 0 instead of that.

Comment: @royherma: that's the right behavior since NSDate represents a precise moment in time.

Answer (score 23):

There is a whole guide to Date and Time Programming. Here is a [relevant section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) which gives you a hint about what to do.

It's where the example code comes from in the other question.

Try and write something based on that and then come back if you have specific questions.

**Edit**

Okay. Here is how I would write the code in it's most basic form.

First, I would extend NSDate.

The header file:

```
//  NSDate+ADNExtensions.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface NSDate (ADNExtensions)

- (NSInteger)numberOfDaysUntil:(NSDate *)aDate;

@end
```

The implementation file:

```
//  NSDate+ADNExtensions.m

#import "NSDate+ADNExtensions.h"


@implementation NSDate (ADNExtensions)


- (NSInteger)numberOfDaysUntil:(NSDate *)aDate {
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:self toDate:aDate options:0];

    return [components day];
}


@end
```

This is very rough code. There is no error checking or validating that the second date is later than the first.

And then I would use it like this (running on a 64-bit, Garbage Collected environment):

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-11-01 00:00:00 +0000"];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2010-11-02 00:00:00 +0000"];

NSInteger difference = [startDate numberOfDaysUntil:endDate];

NSLog(@"Diff = %ld", difference);
```

This is such a shame, because you would have learned a lot more by posting your code and the incorrect outputs and getting more specific help. But if you just want to be a cut-and-paste programmer; take this code and good luck to you.

Comment: can you not just please provide code? honestly, I've tried many things. I've tried using Gregarian and I've tried getting an NSTimeInterval. Please just implement the method?

Comment: Robert, this isn't a "give me the code" website. Ask a question about something that you are stuck on and you will receive *help* to solve that problem. People aren't just going to solve your problem for you. The sooner you understand this, the sooner you can get better answers from people on Stack Overflow. I think Abizer was a bit *too* kind in giving you the code. ;)

Comment: btw, I am not sure that `NSDate` method `dateWithString` existed at all, but at least it was deprecated long time ago, so the second answer is more relevant, you have to use `NSDateFormatter` now

Comment: Heh, I came in looking for a code snippet like this, and now I'm on a big guilt trip, haha!

Comment: You don't need to extend the class just to write a simple helper method like this.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4 implementation**

Method call :

```
let numberOfDays = daysBetweenDates(startDate: fileCreatedDate,endDate: date)
```

Method Implementation:

```
 func daysBetweenDates(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> Int {
        let daysBetween = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
        print(daysBetween.day!)
        return daysBetween.day!
  }
```

**Objective C implementation:**

Method Call:

```
int numberOfDaysSinceFileCreation = [self daysBetweenDates: fileCreatedDate
                                                                   currentDate: today];
```

Method Implementation:

```
- (int) daysBetweenDates: (NSDate *)startDate currentDate: (NSDate *)endDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

    int totalDays = (int)dateComponent.day;
    return totalDays;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

This code seems to work nicely in Swift 2:

```
func daysBetweenDate(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Int
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])

    return components.day
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ObjC Code:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [calender components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
```

Result:

```
int totalDays = (int)dateComponent.day;
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let start = formatter.date(from: "2010-09-01")!
let end = formatter.date(from: "2010-12-01")!
let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: start, to: end).day!
```

Answer (score 2):

The examples mentioned above represent only half picture of the solution because most of the solution only take date value (**e.g: 2010-11-01**) into account when  calculating the difference however in-real world scenario NSDate instance always come together with time and impact the difference on the result as well.

Now, let's talk about the accepted solution where user defined the two dates but not time for them.

```
NSString *start = @"2010-09-01";
NSString *end = @"2010-09-02";

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];
```

Here the time for both dates would be same because no time has been provided for them which means it doesn't impact on the difference calculation.

```
startDate "2010-09-01 12:00 AM"
endDate "2010-09-02 12:00 AM"
```

And the result would be ***days = 1***

Now let's add a specific time for both dates:

```
startDate "2010-09-01 02:00 PM"
endDate "2010-09-02 02:00 AM"
```

After adding a specific time the result would change. Now ***days = 0*** even though day defined in the dates are different. ***It's because the time difference between the two dates is less than 24 hours.***

This calculation method is gonna work fine as long as:

- Desired result is based on time difference.

Or

- Time is not defined for difference.

However, if you wanna ***calculate the days difference based on calendar date change*** then there would a problem because in the above example even though calendar date changed but the result would be ***days = 0***. It's because of the time difference is less than 24 hours.

So, how we can ***calculate the days difference based on calendar date change***. Here is the Apple suggested way of doing it:

```
@implementation NSCalendar (MySpecialCalculations)
- (NSInteger)daysWithinEraFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)endDate {
     NSInteger startDay=[self ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:startDate];
     NSInteger endDay=[self ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit  inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:endDate];
     return endDay - startDay;
}
@end
```

More details are available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1)

*My two cent on the topic to represent the remaining half of the picture.*

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```swift
 let date1Start = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date1)
    let date2Start = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date2)
    let dayDiff2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1Start, to: date2Start).day
```