# Check to see if NSDate was 6 months ago

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, datetime, calendar, nsdate

I've returned a NSDate value back from my server and I need to know how long ago this NSDate was.  I need to write a conditional to see if the date is older than 6 months (in Swift, but I can convert Objective-C).

Here is the NSDate returned, when printed in console:

```
 (2015-09-07 01:22:01 +0000)
```

How do I check if this date above is older than 6 months?

The logic would be something like this:

```
//dateValue is the NSDate returned
var dateValue = log.createdAt
    if (dateValue > 6 months){
    }
    else{
    }
```

Comment: Check those links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198526/nsdate-comparison-using-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889164/get-nsdate-today-yesterday-this-week-last-week-this-month-last-month-var

Comment: [Number of months and days between two NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11654741)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    if date.earlierDate(NSDate(timeInterval: -60*60*24*30*6, sinceDate: NSDate())) == date {
        // 6 months passed since date

    }
```

Comment: OK, do you want to decrease this answer's point or to explain why it isn't good enough for you?

Comment: I did not down-vote you, but that's not a good solution. The number of days varies from moth to month. Much better to use `NSCalendar` methods to compare the date, as suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Etgar, you said "365/2 days are good enough". It depends on the specific need, doesn't it? For some applications you might need to-the-day or even to-the-minute accuracy.

Comment: Thank you @Etgar.  This actually works for me, since I only require a half a year.

Comment: @Etgar 365/2 is a good approach but total days of six consecutive months should be in integer (Six months can't be 182.5 days..). Anyway, this question is all depends on how accurate you want.

Comment: By the way guys, I am only upvoting this answer && marking it as correct because it is the solution for MY problem.. This answer is incorrect if you want it more specific, as @Breek mentioned.  Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the NSCalendar class, and specifically methods like `components:fromDate:toDate:options:`.

If the 2 dates are different by 6 months and one day, is that > 6 months? How about 6 months and 1 second? Or do you only consider the 2 dates to be different by > 6 months if they differ by at least 7 months?

You would need to code your solution differently depending on the exact result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
 if (nextStepDate.earlierDate(Date(timeInterval: -60*60*24*30*6, since: Date())) == date) {
     //do something                                         
 }
```