# calculating number of days, nsdate, ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

The way I am calculating the difference between of 2 dates is

```
NSCalendar *calendar            =   [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *nowAndEnd     =   [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|
                                                        NSDayCalendarUnit|
                                                        NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                                fromDate:now
                                                  toDate:end
                                                 options:0];


NSLog(@"nowAndEnd's day is %d",nowAndEnd.day);
NSLog(@"nowAndEnd's month is %d",nowAndEnd.month);
```

And I am getting back is

```
 nowAndEnd's day is 15
 nowAndEnd's month is 1
```

Question is how can I compute the days from those info. I am asking because some of months have 30 days and some of them  have 31...

Comment: "how can I compute the days" - you **just did that,** didn't you.

Comment: Possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575689/objective-c-calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: the day is 14 but you also have a month so the total days should be 1 *30 + 15 or 1*31 + 15 or even 1*28 + 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is correct, but if you want the calculation to be performed on days only, just use the `NSDayCalendarUnit` alone:

```
NSDateComponents *nowAndEnd    =   [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                fromDate:now
                                                  toDate:end
                                                 options:0];
```

The answer will be directly calculated to the number of days.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. However, the day I am getting is shorter than the actually total days, example is the actually total days is 47, i am getting 46...

Comment: This is strange. Consider in any case that in the calculation the starting day is not included. So from Jan. 1 to Feb. 5 you have (31-1)+5=35 days and not 36.