# how to calculate difference between two times in different dates in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

starttime= 23:00 pm
end time= 5:00 am

I need the summing time of the start time to end time 
i am trying this code but it is not helpful to me

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];

        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *openTime = [formatter dateFromString:start];
        NSDate *closeTime = [formatter dateFromString:end ];
        NSCalendar *calender = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *currentTimeComponents = [calender components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:currentTime];
        NSDateComponents *openTimeComponents = [calender components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:openTime];
        NSDateComponents *closeTimeComponents = [calender components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:closeTime];

        NSUInteger currentTimeSeconds = currentTimeComponents.hour;

        NSUInteger openTimeSeconds = openTimeComponents.hour;

        NSUInteger closeTimeSeconds = closeTimeComponents.hour;

        if (currentTimeSeconds>openTimeSeconds && currentTimeSeconds<closeTimeSeconds) {
            NSLog(@"Time Between Open and Close Time %lu",(unsigned long)currentTimeSeconds);
        }
```

and it shows 0 hors.
please help me some one?
thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401049/date-difference-in-ios/22401427#22401427

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I'd look at using libs/frameworks to accomplish that through their APIs. For example, I've done date operations using [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools)