# Swift days between two NSDates

Tags: ios, swift, date, date-difference

I'm wondering if there is some new and awesome possibility to get the amount of days between two NSDates in Swift / the "new" Cocoa?

E.g. like in Ruby I would do:

```
(end_date - start_date).to_i
```

Comment: I think you still have to use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents (for which there must be hundreds of answers on SO). - If you are looking for something *"new and awesome possibility"* then it would be helpful to show your present solution for comparison.

Comment: This is now very easy, and you don't have to use "NS" anything.  I typed in an answer for 2017, to copy and paste.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You have to consider the time difference as well. For example if you compare the dates `2015-01-01 10:00` and `2015-01-02 09:00`, days between those dates will return as 0 (zero) since the difference between those dates is less than 24 hours (it's 23 hours).

If your purpose is to get the exact day number between two dates, you can work around this issue like this:

```
// Assuming that firstDate and secondDate are defined
// ...

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

// Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
let date1 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(firstDate)
let date2 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(secondDate)

let flags = NSCalendarUnit.Day
let components = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: [])

components.day  // This will return the number of day(s) between dates
```

### Swift 3 and Swift 4 Version

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

// Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: firstDate)
let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: secondDate)

let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
```

Comment: You may actually want to check for 12pm (noon) instead of startOfDayForDate -- should be less likely to bork due to adjusting timezones and DST.

Comment: Setting the dates to noon can be done like this: `calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 00, second: 00, of: calendar.startOfDay(for: firstDate))`

Comment: Shorter version for setting noon (`startOfDay()` seems to be unnecessary): `calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: firstDate)`.

Comment: Can someone please explain me what happens when Calendar.current's timeZone doesn't match the time zone that firstDate/secondDate were initialized with (e.g. from a time formatter) ? What should we do if we want to find the distance in days between a date that we know is in a given time zone (different from current) and the current date in the current time zone - how exactly should we convert the Calendar ?

Comment: Also note that this won't work correctly - e.g. firstDate = 2021-01-13 22:00:00 +0000, startOfDay  = 2021-01-13 22:00:00 +0000, secondDate = 2021-01-14 12:54:46 +0000, startOfDay  = 2021-01-13 22:00:00 +0000 . Even though the secondDate is considered in the next day, using startOfDay will make both dates equal. For this reason I think it is better to use add the hour value / 24  to the day value and round up.

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect. To know why, please look at the posted question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014759/what-is-reliable-way-to-calculate-day-differences-without-taking-time-into-cons However, I do not have a good answer on this.

Comment: Timezone difference would have no effect since the absolute distance is the same. The shift will be on both sides. a - b = c  == (a + 2) - (b + 2)

Answer (score 55):

Here is my answer for Swift 2:

```
func daysBetweenDates(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Int
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Day], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])

    return components.day
}
```

Comment: I successfully used this with components of @vikingosegundo post above. It returns an integer representing the correct number of days between two dates. <thumbs up>

Comment: I like it but the function name should be "daysBetweenDates"

Comment: This returns 0 if we are comparing `today` and `tomorrow`

Answer (score 54):

I see a couple Swift3 answers so I'll add my own:

```
public static func daysBetween(start: Date, end: Date) -> Int {
   Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: start, to: end).day!
}
```

The naming feels more Swifty, it's one line, and using the latest `dateComponents()` method.

Answer (score 41):

Here is very nice, `Date` extension to get difference between dates in years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds

```
extension Date {

    func years(sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: sinceDate, to: self).year
    }

    func months(sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: sinceDate, to: self).month
    }

    func days(sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: sinceDate, to: self).day
    }

    func hours(sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: sinceDate, to: self).hour
    }

    func minutes(sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: sinceDate, to: self).minute
    }

    func seconds(sinceDate: Date) -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: sinceDate, to: self).second
    }

}
```

Comment: `date` should be `sinceDate` in function parameters.

Comment: @TheTiger - Thank you very much for highlighting the biggest mistake of this answer.. I'll practically test and update answer soon.

Comment: My pleasure! I have tested it for `days` and it works fine.

Comment: Good answer. I’d only suggest `func years(since date: Date) -> Int? { return Calendar.current.dateComponents[.year], from: date, to: self).years }`, and you could the call it as `let y = date1.years(since: date2)`. That might be more consistent with modern naming conventions.

Answer (score 29):

I translated my [Objective-C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576575/106435)

```
let start = "2010-09-01"
let end = "2010-09-05"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)
let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(end)

let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


let unit:NSCalendarUnit = .Day

let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil)


println(components)
```

result

```
<NSDateComponents: 0x10280a8a0>
     Day: 4
```

The hardest part was that the autocompletion insists fromDate and toDate would be `NSDate?`, but indeed they must be `NSDate!` as shown in the reference.

I don't see how a good solution with an operator would look like, as you want to specify the unit differently in each case. You could return the time interval, but than won't you gain much.

Comment: Looks like `.DayCalendarUnit` is deprecated. I believe now you should use `.CalendarUnitDay` instead.

Comment: options is now an expected parameter

Comment: Running Swift 2 this works for me: `let components = cal.components(.Day, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])`

Comment: @TaylorAllred just `.Day` now

Answer (score 18):

Update for Swift 3 iOS 10 Beta 4

```
func daysBetweenDates(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.day], from: startDate, to: endDate)
    return components.day!
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Swift 5. Thanks to [Emin Buğra Saral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437254/emin-bu%C4%9Fra-saral/) above for the `startOfDay` suggestion.

```
extension Date {
    
    func daysBetween(date: Date) -> Int {
        return Date.daysBetween(start: self, end: date)
    }
    
    static func daysBetween(start: Date, end: Date) -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        // Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
        let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: start)
        let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: end)
        
        let a = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
        return a.value(for: .day)!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let start = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-01")!
let end = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-01-01")!

let diff = Date.daysBetween(start: start, end: end) // 365
// or
let diff = start.daysBetween(date: end) // 365
```

Comment: it would definitely be better to ***move them both to noon, rather than 00:00*** to avoid many problems.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the answer for Swift 3 (tested for IOS 10 Beta)

```
func daysBetweenDates(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> Int
{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.components([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate, options: [])
    return components.day!
}
```

Then you can call it like this

```
let pickedDate: Date = sender.date
let NumOfDays: Int = daysBetweenDates(startDate: pickedDate, endDate: Date())
    print("Num of Days: \(NumOfDays)")
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**

Working, you need to set the time to be the same for both days, if you are off by seconds it will be wrong

```
func daysBetween(start: Date, end: Date) -> Int {
    let start = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: start)!
    let end = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: end)!
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: start, to: end).day ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The things built into swift are still very basic. As they should be at this early stage. But you can add your own stuff with the risk that comes with overloading operators and global domain functions. They will be local to your module though.

```
let now = NSDate()
let seventies = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)

// Standard solution still works
let days = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitDay, 
           fromDate: seventies, toDate: now, options: nil).day

// Flashy swift... maybe...
func -(lhs:NSDate, rhs:NSDate) -> DateRange {
    return DateRange(startDate: rhs, endDate: lhs)
}

class DateRange {
    let startDate:NSDate
    let endDate:NSDate
    var calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var days: Int {
        return calendar.components(.CalendarUnitDay, 
               fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil).day
    }
    var months: Int {
        return calendar.components(.CalendarUnitMonth, 
               fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: nil).month
    }
    init(startDate:NSDate, endDate:NSDate) {
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate
    }
}

// Now you can do this...
(now - seventies).months
(now - seventies).days
```

Comment: **Don't** use (24*60*60) for the length of a day. This does not take daylight saving time transitions into account.

Comment: I think NSDate would adjust for that since it always uses GMT and daylight saving is just a formatting or localisation upon that. For sure it gets trickier for months, years or anything of really variable length though.

Comment: seconds / (24*60*60) it's wrong for days calculation. you are not counter a leap year with this way

Comment: @DanielSchlaug: Your first solution (using date components) is fine. But from the time interval (which is just a number of seconds) you cannot compute the days, month, ... correctly anymore.

Comment: @MartinR true, I looked into it a bit more and it would seem my solution here is indeed very much inferior to rubys. Indeed a decent solution would require a lot more code. But I do maintain my position that a day is defined well enough at 86400s (±1 leap second happening approximately once per year) that one may calculate a day interval for all practical uses. But I should not have used intuition for time calculation so the criticism is valid.

Comment: @DanielSchlaug: Leap seconds are not the problem, the Unix time does not count them. But in regions with daylight saving time, the clocks are adjusted one hour forward in the spring, and adjusted backward in the autumn. That means that there are days with 23 hours or 25 hours.

Comment: @MartinR I had to try it to believe it but indeed, now that I did I also saw that wikipedia mentions this. You are correct. Thanks for being stubborn with me.

Comment: There, edited to be correct. But the flashiness kind of went away.

Comment: You had to check wikipedia to learn about daylight saving time? But you realized that Sweden changes the time twice a year.

Comment: Well, while I'm always very confused every time DST changes I wasn't so ignorant as to not know about it. I had to check wikipedia to confirm that DST actually makes the definition of the length of a day dependant on location and point in time. My intuition would say that even during a DST change if the time between March 30 12:00 and April 1 12:00 is 23 hours it's actually a little less than a full day. I was wrong.

Comment: it is defined by location, point of time and calendar system. the hebrew calendar has a leap month. there is a great wwdc video: performing calendar calculation — a must-see for every cocoa coder.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer for Swift 3:

```
func daysBetweenDates(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate, inTimeZone timeZone: TimeZone? = nil) -> Int {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    if let timeZone = timeZone {
        calendar.timeZone = timeZone
    }
    let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate.startOfDay, to: endDate.startOfDay)
    return dateComponents.day!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following extension:

```
public extension Date {
    func daysTo(_ date: Date) -> Int? {
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        // Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
        let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: self)
        let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)

        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
        return components.day  // This will return the number of day(s) between dates
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
startDate.daysTo(endDate)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an updated version of Emin's answer for Swift 5 that incorporates the suggestion to use noon instead of midnight as the definitive time for comparing days. It also handles the potential failure of various date functions by returning an optional.

```
///
/// This is an approximation; it does not account for time differences. It will set the time to 1200 (noon) and provide the absolute number
/// of days between now and the given date. If the result is negative, it should be read as "days ago" instead of "days from today."
/// Returns nil if something goes wrong initializing or adjusting dates.
///

func daysFromToday() -> Int?
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current

    // Replace the hour (time) of both dates with noon. (Noon is less likely to be affected by DST changes, timezones, etc. than midnight.)
    guard let date1 = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 00, second: 00, of: calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())),
          let date2 = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 00, second: 00, of: calendar.startOfDay(for: self)) else
    {
        return nil
    }
    
    return calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2).day
}
```

Comment: You should use Swift native Calendar (drop the NS). The use of guard when setting the hour to 12pm is pointless. It will never fail.

Comment: calling startOfDay before setting the hour to noon it is pointless as well.

Comment: This can be a computed variable instead of a function.

Answer (score 2):

There's hardly any Swift-specific standard library yet; just the lean basic numeric, string, and collection types.

It's perfectly possible to define such shorthands using extensions, but as far as the actual out-of-the-box APIs goes, there is no "new" Cocoa; Swift just maps directly to the same old verbose Cocoa APIs as they already exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add my version even though this thread is a year old.  My code looks like this:

```
    var name = txtName.stringValue // Get the users name

    // Get the date components from the window controls
    var dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = txtDOBDay.integerValue
    dateComponents.month = txtDOBMonth.integerValue
    dateComponents.year = txtDOBYear.integerValue

    // Make a Gregorian calendar
    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

    // Get the two dates we need
    var birthdate = calendar?.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
    let currentDate = NSDate()

    var durationDateComponents = calendar?.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: birthdate!, toDate: currentDate, options: nil)

    let numberOfDaysAlive = durationDateComponents?.day

    println("\(numberOfDaysAlive!)")

    txtGreeting.stringValue = "Hello \(name), You have been alive for \(numberOfDaysAlive!) days."
```

I hope it helps someone.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Erin's method updated to Swift 3, This shows days from today (disregarding time of day)

```
func daysBetweenDates( endDate: Date) -> Int 
    let calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current 
    let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date()) 
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: secondDate) 
    return calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2).day! 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice handy one liner :

```
extension Date {
  var daysFromNow: Int {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: self).day!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This returns an absolute difference in days between some `Date` and today:

```
extension Date {
  func daysFromToday() -> Int {
    return abs(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: Date()).day!)
  }
}
```

and then use it:

```
if someDate.daysFromToday() >= 7 {
  // at least a week from today
}
```

Answer (score 1):

easier option would be to create a extension on Date

```
public extension Date {

        public var currentCalendar: Calendar {
            return Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
        }

        public func daysBetween(_ date: Date) -> Int {
            let components = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: date)
            return components.day!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.2

```
extension DateComponentsFormatter {
    func difference(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date) -> String? {
        self.allowedUnits = [.year,.month,.weekOfMonth,.day]
        self.maximumUnitCount = 1
        self.unitsStyle = .full
        return self.string(from: fromDate, to: toDate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All answer is good. But for Localizations we need calculates a number of decimal days in between two dates. so we can provide the sustainable decimal format.

```
// This method returns the fractional number of days between to dates
func getFractionalDaysBetweenDates(date1: Date, date2: Date) -> Double {

    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour], from: date1, to: date2)

    var decimalDays = Double(components.day!)
    decimalDays += Double(components.hour!) / 24.0

    return decimalDays
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 - Days from today until date

```
func daysUntilDate(endDateComponents: DateComponents) -> Int
    {
        let cal = Calendar.current
        var components = cal.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day], from: NSDate() as Date)
        let today = cal.date(from: components)
        let otherDate = cal.date(from: endDateComponents)

        components = cal.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.day], from: (today! as Date), to: otherDate!)
        return components.day!
    }
```

Call function like this

```
// Days from today until date
   var examnDate = DateComponents()
   examnDate.year = 2016
   examnDate.month = 12
   examnDate.day = 15
   let daysCount = daysUntilDate(endDateComponents: examnDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func completeOffset(from date:Date) -> String? {
        
   let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
   formatter.unitsStyle = .brief
        
   return  formatter.string(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date, to: self))
}
```

if you need year month days and hours as string use this

```
var tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!

let dc = tomorrow.completeOffset(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Date {
    func daysFromToday() -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: Date()).day!
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
    func dayCount(dateString: String) -> String{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"
        let fetchedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)


        let day = fetchedDate?.daysFromToday()
        if day! > -1{
            return "\(day!) days passed."
        }else{
        return "\(day! * -1) days left."
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Date {
static func - (recent: Date, previous: Date) -> DateComponents {
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: previous, to: recent).year
    dateComponents.month = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: previous, to: recent).month
    dateComponents.day = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: previous, to: recent).day
    dateComponents.hour = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: previous, to: recent).hour
    dateComponents.minute = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: previous, to: recent).minute
    dateComponents.second = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: previous, to: recent).second
    return dateComponents
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

## 2017 version, copy and paste

```
func simpleIndex(ofDate: Date) -> Int {
    
    // index here just means today 0, yesterday -1, tomorrow 1 etc.
    
    let c = Calendar.current
    let todayRightNow = Date()
    
    let d = c.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 13, of: ofDate)
    let t = c.date(bySetting: .hour, value: 13, of: todayRightNow)
    
    if d == nil || today == nil {
    
        print("weird problem simpleIndex#ofDate")
        return 0
    }
    
    let r = c.dateComponents([.day], from: today!, to: d!)
    // yesterday is negative one, tomorrow is one
    
    if let o = r.value(for: .day) {
        
        return o
    }
    else {
    
        print("another weird problem simpleIndex#ofDate")
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar();
let component1 = calendar.component(.Day, fromDate: fromDate)
let component2 = calendar.component(.Day, fromDate: toDate)
let difference  = component1 - component2
```

Comment: that measures the difference between the number portion of the dates-

I.e. 21st January to 22nd of February will give 1 day, not 32 days as it should

Answer (score -3):

Swift 5.2.4 solution:

```
import UIKit

let calendar = Calendar.current

let start = "2010-09-01"
let end = "2010-09-05"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let firstDate = dateFormatter.date(from: start)!
let secondDate = dateFormatter.date(from: end)!

// Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: firstDate)
let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: secondDate)

let components = calendar.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.day], from: date1, to: date2)

components.day  // This will return the number of day(s) between dates
```

Comment: this is the copy of another answer with just added date parsing, which was never asked for