# Days between 2 NSDates in a calendar year swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, date, nsdate

I'm building a birthday reminder app. I want the user to be able to see how many days it is until somebody's next birthday.

Let's say I have an `NSDate()` = `2015-06-30 07:21:47 +0000`

And the `NSDate` for the birthday = `1985-08-29 12:00:00 +0000`

How would I get the number of days until the next birthday? I've used something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723431/swift-days-between-two-nsdates) which gives a negative number of days since the date's actual beginning (which are in the thousands with birthdates). Then with that I would add 365 to the numerical difference until it was positive but it still returns a wonky number. I'm assuming due to leap years or something.

Is there a method to this I can implement? Somehow equalize the year components so that it's always comparing from the next birthday and not the original birthdate?

Edit:

Here is the function I am using:

```
func daysBetween(date1: NSDate, date2: NSDate) -> Int {

    var calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let date1 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(date1)
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDayForDate(date2)

    let flags = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
    let components = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: date1, toDate: date2, options: nil)

    return components.day
}
```

With the example dates I posted I would use it like this:

```
// sampleDate = 1985-08-29 12:00:00 +0000
daysBetween(sampleDate, date2: NSDate())
// --> 10897
```

Whether positive or negative, the number is in the thousands. I'm looking to equalize that into number of days to the next calendar birthday.

Comment: if it is negative the second day lies before the first one. change the order. And if you have broken code remember to post it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is to compute the *next occurrence* of the (day and month
component of the) birthday after today:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let today = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
let dayAndMonth = cal.components(.CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth,
    fromDate: birthday)
let nextBirthDay = cal.nextDateAfterDate(today,
    matchingComponents: dayAndMonth,
    options: .MatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits)!
```

Remarks:

- The purpose of the `MatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits` option is
  that if the birthday is on February 29 (in the Gregorian calendar), its next occurrence will be
  computed as March 1 if the year is not a leap year.
- You might need to check first if the birthday is *today*, as it seems
  that `nextDateAfterDate()` would return the *next* birthday in that case.

Then you can compute the difference in days as usual:

```
let diff = cal.components(.CalendarUnitDay,
    fromDate: today,
    toDate: nextBirthDay,
    options: nil)
println(diff.day)
```

---

**Update for Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3):**

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let today = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
let dayAndMonth = cal.components([.Day, .Month],
                                 fromDate: birthday)
let nextBirthDay = cal.nextDateAfterDate(today,
                                         matchingComponents: dayAndMonth,
                                         options: .MatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits)!

let diff = cal.components(.Day,
                          fromDate: today,
                          toDate: nextBirthDay,
                          options: [])
print(diff.day)
```

---

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8 GM):**

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let today = cal.startOfDay(for: Date())
let dayAndMonth = cal.dateComponents([.day, .month], from: birthday)
let nextBirthDay = cal.nextDate(after: today, matching: dayAndMonth,
                                matchingPolicy: .nextTimePreservingSmallerComponents)!

let diff = cal.dateComponents([.day], from: today, to: nextBirthDay)
print(diff.day!)
```

Answer (score 4):

Btw, in case anyone needs here is the @Aaron function in Swift 3:

```
func daysBetween(date1: Date, date2: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date1)
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date2)

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.day], from: date1, to: date2)

    return components.day ?? 0
}
```