# Finding the difference in time between two NSDates Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have two NSDate objects: startDate and endDate, both are NSDate objects. I want to find the difference between these two dates. I know there is a resolved question about this already ([Getting the difference between two NSDates in (months/days/hours/minutes/seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds)), but I want to know if there is a quicker way to do this (less execution code). Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "quicker"? Faster execution or less code? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27182410/1187415) to the referenced question solves it in a single statement, so what are you looking for?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes if you look at the second answer to your linked question you can do this: 
`let interval = laterDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(earlierDate)`

Comment: how can be this turned into days?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132159/days-between-2-nsdates-in-a-calendar-year-swift

Comment: let interval = laterDate.timeIntervalSince(earlierDate as Date) : difference in seconds in Swift 3

Comment: Use timeIntervalSinceNow if using the current date