# Find different between hours

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate

I have two hours and minutes :

I got this time from user. that what is your start time and end time.

```
1) 10:00 AM
2) 06:00 PM
```

Now i have to find total time user worked for. Means it fetch 
total time: 8:00

How do i get it ?

I am ding this code in Objective C.

Comment: elaborate your question ? how to get above time which you are specified ?

Comment: no need reason that where is come from nevertheless i updated my question. @KKRocks

Comment: although it's objective c, still difference between 10 and 18 is 8, not 9.

Comment: Yeah, Updated. Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift days between two NSDates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723431/swift-days-between-two-nsdates)

Comment: it finding diff between date. How do i get diff between hours & min ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will help you.

```
NSString *time1 = @"10.00 pm";
NSString *time2 = @"06.00 pm";
NSDate *date1;
NSDate *date2;
{
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh.mm a"];
  date1 = [formatter dateFromString:time1];
  date2 = [formatter dateFromString:time2];
  [formatter release];
}
 NSTimeInterval interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2]; //[date1 timeIntervalSince1970] - [date2 timeIntervalSince1970];
  int hour = interval / 3600;
 int minute = (int)interval % 3600 / 60;

NSLog(@"%@ %dh %dm", interval<0?@"-":@"+", ABS(hour), ABS(minute));
```

Comment: what is   timeIntervalSince1970] - [date2 timeIntervalSince1970];
 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this!

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current

    let datecomponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: start as Date, to: someDateTime as Date)
    let hours = datecomponents.hour!
    print("hours: \(hours)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
-(NSString *)startTime:(NSString *)startTime AndWithAndTime:(NSString *)endTime{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:startTime];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:endTime];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    int hours = (int)interval / 3600;             // integer division to get the hours part
    int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
    NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", hours, minutes];
    return timeDiff;
}

NSLog(@"%@",[self startTime:@"10:00 AM" AndWithAndTime:@"06:00 PM"]);
```