# How to check how long ago was the app last opened

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift4

In my app, I want to check how long ago did the user last open the app and if it was 14 days or more, the user would receive a prompt saying they should be more active but I'm not too sure how to check how long ago was the app last used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the current date in UserDefaults whenever the app becomes inactive (using the `applicationWillResignActive` app delegate).

Load the stored date (if any) from UserDefaults whenever the app becomes active (using the `applicationDidBecomeActive` app delegate). If there is a date (there won't be the first time the app is used), calculate the number of days between the retrieved date and the current date.

See [Swift days between two NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723431/swift-days-between-two-nsdates) for methods to calculate the difference between two dates. In short, you use the `Calendar dateComponents(_, from:, to:)` method.

Comment: But how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

In your `AppDelegate`:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "LastOpened")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    guard let lastOpened = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "LastOpened") as? Date else {
        return
    }
    let elapsed = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: lastOpened, to: Date())
    if elapsed >= 14 {
        // show alert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

save current Date(UserDefaults) on `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` & `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)` methods.

check it on `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`