# Change value after the end of the Day (SwiftUi)

Tags: date, swiftui, nsdate

I am new to the SwiftUi.

I have written a code that saves the number of Days the user has picked. The point of my question that I do not know how to make it to subtract one day every new day.

For example, we have 70 days the user has picked. I want every day to be like 70-1 = 69, 69-1 = 68, and so on.

Thank you for reading and I'd really appreciate any ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to build a countdown app or similar.
Did you check this post?

[Swift days between two NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723431/swift-days-between-two-nsdates)

Comment: This would function better as a comment, as it doesn't actually provide an answer.