# dateComponents returns wrong number of days between two dates

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have two dates. `startDate` and `endDate` which are one day apart. From the print function I get:

`startDate`: `2023-01-01 05:07:33 +0000`
`endDate`: `2023-01-01 17:08:04 +0000`

Of course this is UTC so the day is inaccurate but if I get the `Calendar.Component` `.day` for each date then I get `1` and `2` respectively which is what I expect.

I am trying to calculate the number of days between these two dates using:
`Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: startDate, to: endDate).day`

However this is returning `0`. What am I don't wrong here? From what I understand since this function is using the `Calendar` then it should ignore the `UTC` format and return `1`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with timezone. The difference is 12 hours, 31 seconds. That's less than 1 day. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28163560/20287183 for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function you use calculates the difference in *full* days between the two dates and not if they are on different days

This can be easily verified with the below example

```
let endDate = Date.now
let firstDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -23, to: endDate)!
print(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: firstDate, to: endDate).day!)
let secondDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -24, to: endDate)!
print(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: secondDate, to: endDate).day!)
```

which prints

> 0
> 1

The same goes for an hour where -59 minutes returns 0 and -60 returns 1