# Cocoa - Calculate working days between two dates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, date, nsdate

I new in cocoa programing and I want to know how I get the number of working days between to dates. So only from Monday to Friday. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDate *startDate = ...;
NSDate *stopDate = ...;

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
startDate = [df dateFromString:[df stringFromDate:startDate]]; // get start of the day

NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
comps.day = 1; // one day in NSDateComponents

NSUInteger count = 0;
while ([stopDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate] >= 0) {

    NSInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:startDate].weekday;

    if (weekday != 1 && weekday != 6) ++count; // filter out weekend days - 6 and 1

    startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:startDate options:0]; // increment start day
}
```

Comment: You started out so good with `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`, and then somehow ended up with `3600 * 24`. Don't use seconds to increment days! Not every day has 24 hours and not every hour has 3600 seconds. Dates and times are a pain.

Comment: @JustSid, please give some direct examples on "Not every day has 24 hours and not every hour has 3600 seconds." Thanks anyway, updated.

Comment: Switch from/to daylight saving times for example. Leap seconds. Sometimes whole days are removed or added to bring calendars in sync.

Comment: Works fine, if the dates are in same month, but if is selected for example: 7/20/2014 to 8/20/2014 there is a problem, the program stops working. I see that if I select 8/28/2014 and the second thate greater than 30 (I mean 8/31/2014) there is a problem also. Please help.

Comment: @JustinAndrew, sorry for mistake, please change NSCalendarWrapComponents to zero (see edited answer)