# Swift3 - comparing two different date formats

Tags: swift3, date-format, date-difference

I have a date coming from an API in the following format: `"2016-12-05T05:00:00.000Z"`

How can I find the difference in days between the above date and current date in swift3?

Thanks

Comment: parse it with `DateFormatter` and compare with `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575689/objective-c-calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates/4576575#4576575)

Converted it into Swift 3

You can first extract the date from above string and store in `start`. Then take the current date into `end`

**Find Current Date**:

```
let date = NSDate()
var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var end = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
```

**Find Difference**:

```
var start: String = "2010-09-01"
var f = DateFormatter()
f.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var startDate: Date? = f.date(from: start)
var endDate: Date? = f.date(from: end)
var gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
var components = gregorianCalendar.dateComponents([.day] ,from: startDate!, to: endDate!)
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you