# how to determine when two NSDates are 1 week apart?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, foundation

I'm my app I have an NSMutableArray, and each entry has an NSMutableDictionary with several Key-Value pairs. One of these pairs contains the date of the entry. For one of the functions of my app I need to determine which entries are exactly 1 week apart from each other (i.e from Sunday to Sunday) and sum the data from one of the Key-Value pairs for each day of that week.

How should I go about doing this?

Note: By Sunday to Sunday I mean just Sunday in general and not exactly say sunday at 9PM to Sunday at 9PM.

Comment: Sunday to Saturday is not "exactly one week apart". That's six days and some fraction.

Comment: Please don't only tag the platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Number of days between two NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)

Answer (score 3):

You can sort your entries by date (in ascending order for example). After that you can calculate difference in days between all subsequent dates, basically `diff[n] = dayDiff(dates[n], dates[n-1])`. Therefore for each `dates[n]` you can find a date 7 days from it quite fast - just sum `diffs` from `n` until you reach end of array (=> there is no such date) OR sum is equal to 7 (=> you found it) OR sum is bigger than 7 (=> there is no such date).

Don't try to use milliseconds or something like that to get difference in days. Dates are much more than milliseconds from some reference point. Use `NSCalendar` for this

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *cs = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                   fromDate:date1
                                     toDate:date2
                                    options:0];
NSInteger diffInDays = cs.days;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using NSDateComponents. You could convert both dates A and B into just their day components, then check for a difference of 7.