# Read UTC in ios and subtract to date

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I get fro server dateTime (deadline) string like `"2013-03-29 04:12:35"` and I need to make stopwatch which is going to show in label estimated time to deadline in format `hours::minutes:seconds`. I thought to convert deadline to utc and then read from phone current utc, subtract and convert to format `hours::minutes:seconds`. How to read UTC in ios and convert string to UTC ( Is there easier way to accomplish this task) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *utcDateString = @"2013-03-29 04:12:35";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
//DateFormatter by default will be in local timezone.
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[formatter setFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *utcDate = [formatter dateFromString:utcDateString];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
```

Now you can use to find the date components(hour,minutes,seconds) using the method mentioned in this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147949/767730)