# Calculate duration between two dates(finding upcoming/old birthdays) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

How can i calculate duration between two dates. like[image]
[image]
I am getting contacts birthday list from contacts framework. Now i want to compare Today date with user DOB value and i should display the "remaining days count"(birthday).

For Example:
In contacts i added one user like: DOB: dd/MM/yyyy -->12/04/1960

now today date is: 25/04/2016

I want to get the upcoming birthday date(duration between two dates)

**o/p:** 18 days

How can i get this

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575689/objective-c-calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: Hello, @user6170930, why you're giving negative mark to my question. whatever you suggested me those links are calculating hole days like (user DOB:28/04/1958) and today date is: 25/04/2016==> it's calculating the whole difference, but i am looking for only Result like:3 days

Comment: Please tell me the solution for this? -- @user6170930

Answer (score 3):

Try below line of code. you will get the solution.

```
NSDateComponents *components;
NSInteger days;

components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSDayCalendarUnit 
    fromDate: startDate toDate: endDate options: 0];
days = [components day];
```

Comment: @Mannam Brahmam if this solves your problem then upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit |     NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [currCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:fistDate   toDate:secondDate  options:0];
int months = [conversionInfo month]; // to get number of months
int days = [conversionInfo day]; //  to get number of days
int hours = [conversionInfo hour]; // to get hour difference
int minutes = [conversionInfo minute]; // to get hour difference
```

copied from [Difference between two NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147851/difference-between-two-nsdates)