# How do I calculate date count difference between my app installed and device date from objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, nsdate

How do I calculate **date count difference** between **two days** in objectice C formate.

Comment: Try this answer posted to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739550/1262527

Answer (score 2):

Check if Installation Date is Registered or not, if registered the Calculate date otherwise register it.

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"IDate"])
{
    NSDate *iDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"IDate"];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:iDate];
    int diff=interval/86400;//for converting seconds into days.
    NSLog(@"%d Days",diff);
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"IDate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: its gave idea for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you mean something like a "trial time" and after that you have to register: I would do as followed:

```
    NSDate *installDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"InstallationDate"];
    if(installDate)
    {
        // time in Seconds
        long int timePassed = [installDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1;
        NSLog(@"%ld", timePassed);

        // now do your calculations and compare
    }
    else // first start
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"InstallationDate"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"InstallationDate"]);
    }
```

(as addition to Danny's post)

Answer (score 0):

Store your device installed date in `NSUserDefaults` once its first run and then calculate that with the current date.

```
NSTimeInterval diff = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]; // in seconds
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't take into account time changes, leap years, etc.  You should not calculate "days" between two dates this way.