# Find continuous days the app is used

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, counter

I am developing one ios app now. I have feature in which i have to display a continuous days the app is used.

Means if i use app for 3 days constantly i have to display 3.

And if i have not used it for one day. The counter should reset.

I am using this function to calculate days.

```
- (int)daysBetween:(NSDate *)dt1 and:(NSDate *)dt2 {
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:dt1 toDate:dt2 options:0];
    return [components day];
}
```

I am saving last used date. and pass two parameter last used date and current date in it.

But by this function if i used app at 11.30 PM and again used it at 1.00 AM it will not increment day.

Comment: Add it to NSUserDefaults...

Comment: @IronManGill Yes i am saving last usage date in NsUser Default. But the function only gives me >0 value if it 24 Hours spent between two dates. If two NsDate have 1 Hour difference and date changes it will not give me correct value.

Comment: its better to used google analytics...

Comment: @TapanNathvani, Yes but i have also other feature depended on this.I don't want to get countinous days the app used. actually i want some feature used countinous used in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this because you are not considering the time part of the dates, you need to use `rangeOfUnit:`.

I suggest to use the @Brain functions mentioned in this SO question:

[Number of days between two NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)