# calculate timeIntervalSinceDate for over a month?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Maybe i am missing something very stupid so forgive me .
Comparing a date that is 1 month later than another date , starts to give me strange numbers.
I guess its because the result is `float` ? Here is how i do the comparison :

```
    int daysToCheckUses=60;
    long seconds=60*60*24*daysToCheckUses;
    NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
        if([today timeIntervalSinceDate:date]>seconds) //date can be more than 60 days old
```

Is there something wrong with this,when using big numbers? for example when the interval is 1 month i get `518400`,but for 3 months i get `18662400000`  i know that the comparisons returns `float` number that can't hold these numbers. I am afraid also to get a crash when a few months will pass.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get"?

Answer (score 1):

This method to calculate a big distance is not that good, i found a great and better way for this using a great answer from here :

[Number of days between two NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)

Where the comparison is for days, than months will only give a few 100's integer .