# Get difference between two dates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two dates in 24 hours formate like (dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm). I want to get a difference between these two dates.

My Code : This is getting only dates, I want a number of days and remaining time in hours also. (like 6days 5 hours)

```
    NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    int numberOfDays = secondsBetween / 86400;
    NSLog(@"There are %d days in between the two dates.", numberOfDays);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of days between two NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSDateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponentsformatter?language=objc) can do that

```
NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:secondsBetween]);
```

See [`NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponentsformatterunitsstyle?language=objc) for other styles.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3+

you can use date-components, like:

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 12345678)

let dateComponets = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour], from: date1, to: date2)
```

then you can see the difference in days:

```
debugPrint(dateComponets.day, dateComponets.hour) // 142 (days), 22 (hours)
```

---

## ObjC

same approach, but different syntax:

```
NSDate * date1 = [NSDate new];
NSDate * date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:12345678];

NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:date1 toDate:date2 options:0];
```

then the difference in days:

```
NSLog(@"%d, %d", dateComponents.day, dateComponents.hour); // 142 (days), 22 (hours)
```

Comment: How to pass my end date, here date1 is current date what about my date

Comment: `date1` and `date2` are your dates, I guess, just need to replace them, with the desired ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct EventDate {
var monthYear: [String]?
var monthNumber: [String]?
var year: [String]?
var month: [String]?
init(monthYear: [String]?,monthNumber:[String]?,year:[String]?,month:[String]?) {
    self.monthYear = monthYear
    self.monthNumber = monthNumber
    self.year = year
    self.month = month
}

}

func getMonthAndYearBetween(from start: String, to end: String) -> EventDate {

    var monthYear: [String] = []
    var monthNumber: [String] = []
    var years: [String] = []
    var months: [String] = []

    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    guard let startDate = format.date(from: start),
        let endDate = format.date(from: end) else {
            return EventDate(monthYear: [], monthNumber: [], year: [], month: [])
    }

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(Set([.month]), from: startDate, to: endDate)

    var allDates: [String] = []
    let dateRangeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateRangeFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"

    for i in 0 ... (components.month! + 1) {
        guard let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: i, to: startDate) else {
            continue
        }

        let formattedDate = dateRangeFormatter.string(from: date)
        allDates += [formattedDate]

        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"
        let monyr = df.string(from: date)
        monthYear.append(monyr)
        df.dateFormat = "MM"
        let monNO = df.string(from: date)
        monthNumber.append(monNO)
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy"
        let yr = df.string(from: date)
        years.append(yr)
        df.dateFormat = "MMM"
        let mon = df.string(from: date)
        months.append(mon)

    }
    return EventDate(monthYear: monthYear, monthNumber: monthNumber, year: years, month: months)
}
```

you can get like this

```
let eventDate = Date().getMonthAndYearBetween(from: startDate, to: endDate)
```